# How can I change back to trial?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform, trial

I accidentally "upgraded" my account to non trial. I'm still using the trial and needing to test stuff while still in the developing period.
The credit card I put is not the credit card that will be when I upgrade my account intentionally.
So in short words, I need to change my status back to "trial" so Google won't accidentally charge me even though I still get the trial privileges.

Comment: This question is off-topic.  You need to contact google support.

Comment: I talked to someone in the Google Sales and they directed me here.

Comment: Please contact [Google Cloud billing](https://support.google.com/cloud/?hl=en#topic=3340599), if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Though you've upgraded your account, your free trial conditions are still valid. The charge first goes to the credit remaining, if the account is still within its 60 days trial period. For opening case with the billing team, you can use this link: https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change back from paid to trial, however this is not necessary. The remaining credit from the trail will be applied to your account, so you will get just as much for free.

If you don't want to be charged you can disable billing for your project (although this will disable many services).