# I upgraded my Google Cloud Free Tier to paid account, how to downgrade?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-billing

By mistake, I upgraded my Google Cloud Free Tier to paid account, how to downgrade back to free tier?

Answer (score 2):

Please, [contact Google Cloud Platform Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing), and they'll assist you best in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Extremely confusing. It's so easy to clock the wrong button on the slow web UI and then the billing is main issue to worry about - completely unnecessary and distracting

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, but [look at this reply to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32727286/12257250) - you can still use your free tier credits until they run out.

Answer (score 0):

On your projects, you can disable the billing account. By the way, you could only use the free tier on this project and your paid account will never used. But there is some limitation on this (compute usage, AppEngine deployment,...)

At cost perspective, there is no difference between a paid account and a free tier while you still have credit on your account, you will never charge.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other answers, you cannot downgrade. Google now requires a credit card or other billing instrument for payments. You will not get charged for service usage that falls under the free or always free tiers but you will be charged for services that do not fall under those tiers. If you remove or cancel your credit card, your services will be suspended.